# Meteor: "Hacking" accounts-ui package by Meteor Development Group

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-interface, meteor

I like the simpleness of the accounts-ui user interface.
However, I would like to edit some parts of it just a little bit.
Also, I would like to have a look at how it does what it does....

I wish to find and download the source codes of the accounts-ui package and mess around with it and integrate it into my Meteor App.

I have a few questions:
By doing `meteor add accounts-ui`  the accounts-ui files must be added to the project otherwise why would the Meteor app be able to use it. However...

1.) Where do we find it inside our Meteor project???
I have tried the `.meteor` folder and I couldn't find it...

2.) Is there a Github repository for it?
I have also tried searching for it and I couldn't find it....

I wanted to change the 'Sign-in' text of the

```
<a id="login-sign-in-link" class="login-link-text">Sign in ▾</a>
```

To Sign-in/Sign-up
I've tried doing JQUERY on it.
It works during first load but after u click on it and close the modal again then it reverts back to Sign-in....

I like all the other convenience that accounts-ui provides so I am thinking of just making some editing on accounts-ui if I can get my hands on it....

Thank you

Comment: You can find the code for accounts-ui inside of the Meteor repo on github here: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/tree/master/packages/accounts-ui-unstyled .  As for customization, the package mentioned in Radu's answer provides a much higher level of customization.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to customize your login forms you better use `useraccounts:core`. Actually, you don't have to add the **core** package but directly the styling framework you're already using (such as `useraccounts:bootstrap`). Read the guides here: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md

From here you can simply add

```
{{> atForm}}
```

and that will give you at least 4 ready made forms (sign-in, register, forgot password, reset password).

Text configurations you wished to change in the original package are easy to edit with **useraccounts** like here: https://github.com/meteor-useraccounts/core/blob/master/Guide.md#configuring-texts